# Third nested divs are refusing to stay within container

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to nest final divs inside my responsive square grid, but the last squares just refuse to stay within their rows. Everything works until I start adding `.inside_square`.

HTML :

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="main_square">
      <div class="inside_row">
        <div class="inside_square"></div>
        <div class="inside_square"></div>
        <div class="inside_square"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="inside_row"></div>
      <div class="inside_row"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="main_square"></div>
    <div class="main_square"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="main_square"></div>
    <div class="main_square"></div>
    <div class="main_square"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 45.5vw;
    height: 30vw;
    margin: auto;
}

.row {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
}

.main_square {
    border: 1px solid green;
    width: 15vw;
    height: 15vw;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: -4px;
}

.inside_row {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 100%;
    height: 33%;
}

.inside_square {
    border: 1px solid pink;
    width: 33%;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: -4px;
}
```

Adding the final squares ruin the layout from [image I](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yR78T.jpg) to [image II](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUtjw.jpg)

How do I fix this problem? Bonus problem is how do I fix borders going slightly over their boundaries even though I set their size with %?

Comment: Border's are *added* to an element's width unless you apply the property `box-sizing: border-box;` to your element. Also, `display: inline-block;` will render any line-breaks in your code as spaces, as the elements are treated like in-line text. Consider using a simpler and more modern approach like [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) instead.

Comment: Fyi HTML isn't code.

Comment: Tried using flexbox but it refused to treat my second rows as rows, instead it treated it as columns and I couldnt get to change it. I applied flexbox to the .inside-row though and it seems to works, for now.

Comment: Oh well, it doesnt, after applying squares to all bigger squares layout breaks again...

Comment: how exactly you want the layout to look like?

Comment: not sure if this is what you are trying to achieve https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NgwrOj

Comment: Geeky, I want to fill bigger squares with 9 pink squares in each main square. Your solution (and mine) doesnt work when you start filling other main squares with smaller squares, layout breaks. And breaks with every solution I try